# how to send email automatically

Tags: c#, email, webforms

I am trying to send an email automatically using timer. the given below code is I have used for send email. But it is not responding. While using the same code under button click event, its working perfectly. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
namespace AlertMail
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
            string em = "toAddress@gmail.com";
            loginInfo.To.Add(em.ToString());
            loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("fromAddress@gmail.com");
            loginInfo.Subject = "Alert Information";

            loginInfo.Body = "Hai";
            loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("fromAddress@gmail.com", "Password");
            smtp.Send(loginInfo);
            label6.Text = "Alert is send to your email..!!";
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well if the code works fine, perhaps the timer isn't enabled? Have you set a breakpoint in the event and verified it's running? Also, you don't need to call `.ToString()` on a string (you do this on `em`).

Comment: @RufusL : Thank you. No its working, Actually timer is disabled, so that it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

In many web application we need to send schedule(automatic) emails and we schedule them.
 like:

1. Sends emails on a regular basis
2. Send the message at daily, weekly, monthly or yearly intervals.

For this, we normally used windows services or windows application.

As we know the web server IIS is continuously running, we can add a timer in the application and the timer can manage all these activities

```
//Inside Global.ascx 
      void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      // Code that runs on application startup
     System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      // Set the Interval to 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds).
     myTimer.Interval = 5000;
     myTimer.AutoReset = true;
     myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
     myTimer.Enabled = true; 
     } 

 public void myTimer_Elapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     // use your mailer code 
    clsScheduleMail objScheduleMail = new clsScheduleMail();
    objScheduleMail.SendScheduleMail();   
}

// inside your class
public void SendScheduleMail()
{ 
  // Write your send mail code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I need to run something on a schedule on a Windows server, I use a Scheduled Task.  You can write your e-mail piece as a Console application, save it to a location on the server, and then have a scheduled task run the application on a given time interval.  I'm not sure what version of Windows you are running, but these instructions apply to Windows 2008, Windows 8, and Windows 2012:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx